# How to use onMove to reorder horizontal lists in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a list where I can currently reorder elements using drag and drop.

```
@State private var contacts = [
        "John",
        "Alice",
        "Bob",
        "Foo",
        "Bar"
    ]

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(contacts, id: \.self) { contact in
            Text(contact)
        }.onMove { from, to in
            contacts.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change this list so that the elements are aligned horizontally, rather than vertically as they are now, while still maintaining the ability to drag and drop elements to reorder them. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: not possible with `List`. You have to build your own draggable support for  `ScollView`

Comment: Ok thank you. If you post as an answer (and potentially provide some places I can look for how to do this?) I will mark it as the correct solution.